# I'm looking for an app or programme that can draw similar to Sketchup

Tags: software-recommendation, vector

Looking for a replacement for Sketchup in Ubuntu.  Simple is good.  I only really need to draw plan view.

Comment: Have you considered LibreOffice Draw?

Comment: you can also see here: https://alternativeto.net/software/google-sketchup/?platform=linux

Answer (score 1):

FreeCAD has the ability to make drawings in plan view.

FreeCAD is an open source CAx RAD based on OpenCasCade, Qt and Python. It features some key concepts like macro recording, workbenches, ability to run as a server and dynamically loadable application extensions and it is designed to be platform independent.

To install FreeCAD in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install freecad
```